# Inheriting Or Creating Static methods is better in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a Common class

say

```
Public class Trans
{

//Access modifiers like the following 20 are there and 20 methods

 protected internal string TopVenueCd
 {
            get { return this.Ticket.GetValue("venueCd", "").TopOne().GetStringValue(); }
 }

}
```

I am inheriting this class to where ever i need.
But in that in all the classes where i am inheriting i dont need all methods.

So I can create that as a static class and access it where ever it is required..

Which is wiser ?

And please give reasons for that as i am not clear in depth in oops in performance..
Thanks for all replies..

**UPDATE**

My Aim is to segregate one Collection related process separately in a class. 
( I am using mongoDb ) One Important  Collection which is heavily used and it s a big one with nested document.

Still the schema is not fixed and freezed. Still working on it to get a better solution.

So if i take the logical manipulation of that particular Collection separately in a class, if i change the schema i can change only this class.That is intention.

Since i m a beginner in C#, oops this question arise..

How to do this segregation well in best practice ?

Comment: Well you can use `abstract class` since you dont want the implementation of all methods in your derived class

Comment: @Kyle abstract classes/methods are only used in a case where different child classes have Different implementations of a single method and they HAVE TO be implemented by the child class eg;
`abstract class Animal{ public abstract function makeNoise();}  class Dog extends Animal{ public function makeNoise(){ this.doBark();}}  class Cat extends Animal{ public function makeNoise(){ this.doMeow();}}` in this guy's case, he's saying that sometimes certain methods will be used, and sometimes they won't

Comment: this class cannot be made static, anything with get/set can't be made static, you can create a singleton, but only if you're only planning on creating one of these objects, otherwise, you create a singleton with an iterator implemented in it, of course that collection of objects will be manipulated by everything, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance is so much misused as a "copy stuff into my class"-feature. It should be used for real inheritance situations (is-a-relation).

If static methods work as well, definitively use that. Use extension methods to make your static methods easy to find.

Why?

- Because inheritance is the much higher coupling. You couldn't easily decouple it by using interfaces and injected services in the future.
- While you can access static methods from many helper classes, you can only have one base class. If you need more stuff in the future, your base classes will become too big. Because you always inherit everything, all your classes become too big.
- When you need a base class for real inheritance in the future, you can't give your class another base class anymore.

Therefore, simply do not use inheritance if in doubt. There are rare really good applications of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with your design if you need to inherit a class when you don't need all the methods.

It might be that your base class is a [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), and it has too much responsibilities, or that you have lumped up a few non-essential functionalities into a common base, which is a violation of the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Comment: Yeah.I accepted.I updated my post a bit.Please Check my requirement.